# Moving zeros to the beginning of an array

Tags: arrays, swift, data-structures

I need help with my solution the algorithm question below. My code works but the elements to right side of the array are not supposed to be sorted.

You are given an array of integers. Rearrange the array so that all zeroes are at the beginning of the array.For example,a = [4,2,0,1,0,3,0] -> [0,0,0,4,1,2,3]

```
 func moveZerosTotheFront(arrays:[Int] )->[Int] {
    var result = arrays
    var boundary = 0
    for index in 0...arrays.count-1{
        if result[index] == 0{
            print(index )
            result.swapAt(index, boundary)
            boundary+=1
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

Comment: What should happen with the non-zero numbers? Should they stay in the same order, or get sorted? Your first example matches none of these two.

Comment: The non zeros should not be in the same order. It should maintain its original state

Comment: @RetroBoomin can you choose and checkmark the solution? It helps the poster.

Answer (score 3):

It's because of your use of `swapAt`. Think about what happens the very first time you encounter a zero. At that time, `boundary` is `0` and so the value there is `4`; you are swapping that `4` to replace the first `0` you encountered, which is *after* the `2`, thus violating the terms of the problem.

The truth is that you don't need to swap *anything*. You're way overthinking this! You know perfectly well that the only things to be "moved" are `0` values. So just eliminate all the `0` values and stick that same number of `0` values on the front. You know what "that same number" is because that's how much shorter the array got when you eliminated the `0` values.

```
func moveZerosTotheFront(_ array:[Int])->[Int] {
    let result = array.filter {$0 != 0}
    return Array(repeating: 0, count: array.count - result.count) + result
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Matt's solution works, but if you're like me and prefer not to use variables, here is an alternative:

```
func moveZerosTotheFront(arrays: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    arrays
        .enumerated()
        .sorted(by: { lhs, rhs in
            lhs.element == 0 || lhs.offset < rhs.offset
        })
        .map(\.element)
}
```

Give priority to zero values, else give priority to smallest index.

Comment: Very nice way of looking at it.

Comment: This is a really beautiful answer. Using offsets to keep things in position is a sorting technique I hadn't thought of before. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've not worked on swift, but just thought of sharing an approach which has O(n) time complexity and O(n) space complexity.

1.You can create an extra array(named as sortingZeros) of same size.

2.givenArr = [4,2,0,1,0,3,0] --> Iterate the gvien array from the last index and add the non zero values from the last position of the extra array.
For Ex :

```
var i = givenArr.length-1;
var j = givenArr.length-1;
for (iterate in the reverse direction) {
  if (givenArr[i] != 0) {
     sortingZeros[j] = givenArr[i];
     j--; 
  }
  i--;
}
```

3. Once all the non-zero values are added to the new array the zeros would automatically be at the front of the array.

Comment: Can you elaborate on `iterate in the reverse direction`? Who's iterated, the array, i, j? Seems you're accessing the array via `i` and `j`, so the iteration direction should not matter.

Comment: @Cristik The "givenArr" is iterated from the last index to zeroth index...so that the non-zero values can be identified and can be written in new array(sortingZeros) created..

i is used for checking the values in "givenArr". j is used for writing the non-zero values identified in givenArr and will be written at the end of  new Array(sortingZeros)... So when the flow is completed zeros will be automatically in the front and non-zero values will be at the end without change in order.

Answer (score 0):

Your code was almost there, but it had some flaws, let me point them:

- you need to iterate backwards, from the end of the array, and move zeroes as you encounter them: `for index in (0...arrays.count-1).reversed()`
- the `swapAt` needs to happen at each step, as you want to shift right all array elements by the number of zeroes encountered so far
- the swap arguments were not entirely correct, you need to swap `index+boundary` with `index`
- you need to check the original array, not `result[index] == 0`, to decide if to increment the shifting offset or not

With the above in mind, your function would look like this:

```swift
func moveZerosTotheFront(_ array: [Int] ) -> [Int] {
    var result = array
    var offset = 0
    for index in array.indices.reversed() {
        result.swapAt(index+offset, index)
        if array[index] == 0 {
            offset += 1
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

I also replaced the `(0...array.count-1).reversed()` part by `array.indices.reversed()`, for a more Swift-ier style.